# Adding and removing className dynamically in an inifinite loop

Tags: reactjs, carousel, classname

I built a carousel that displays 3 slides. While the center one is 100% width displayed, the left and right ones are only visible 10% of the width.

After accessing the website, the carousel starts moving automatically using this:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.carouselTimer = setInterval(() => {
            this.handleButtonNext();
        }, 5000);
    }
```

And if I manually change the slide, I reset the interval that changes the slides automatically using clearInterval and setInterval again.

In order to be able to add a sliding animation, I want to change the state properties (leftSlide & rightSlide) from false to true and after the animation back to false.

I tried to change the properties from false to true inside *handleButtonNext()* method making changes here:

```
        <Slide 
                className={` ${this.state.leftSlide ? ' left-slide' : ''} ${this.state.rightSlide ? 'right-slide' : ''}`}
        ...the rest of slides.../>
```

The dilemma I have and the problem I encountered so far is that I cannot remove the added class in such a manner that it won't break the autoplay feature.

I tried using a reset method and restarting the autoplay, but no solution seems to be working.

**Without the removal of the added class, the autoplay (and reset in case of a manual change of the slides) works just fine, but that's not enough.**

***This is the method that handles next button:***

```
    handleButtonNext() {
        this.setState({
            rightSlide: true
        });
        // this.wait1ms = setInterval(() => {
        // }, 1100); (useless attempt)
        this.setState({
            activeSlide: this.nextSlide()
        })
    }

    nextSlide() {
        let nextIndex = this.state.activeSlide+1;
        return (nextIndex>this.state.slides.length-1) ? 0 : nextIndex ;
    }

*The method is used here:*
    <a className="button-container right">
        <div className="carousel-button next" onClick={this.handleButtonNext}></div>
    </a>
#same for the left button
```

I need to mention that I do not master React and I am fairly new to it. Thank you for the time you will take to help me! I wish you a great day.

*L.E: I forgot to mention that I would like to do this using **class** component, not the hooks that function provides.*

Comment: # try to make it shorter

Comment: Where is the code for your `this.handleButtonNext`?

Comment: are you using a library for slider, or you're creating your own? does it have a autoplay feature already, so you want to add animation to it? if it doesn't have animation, how autoplay works? it just changes the image without animation?

Comment: @yaya I created it from scratch, same with autoplay feature, using setInterval and calling the method that changes the slide to the next one every 5 seconds. And yes, it changes the entire slide (text, image etc) without any animation, instant and hideous.

Comment: Thanks, but please add this information to the questions itself.

Comment: `wait1ms` is a useless interval, are you trying to delay the second `setState`? Because that's not how you do it.

Comment: And by the way, you put `handleButtonPrev` in the question instead of `handleButtonNext`, but I'm assuming they are similar.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi yes that was what I tried to do in the first place but I commented those lines since I realized that they are pointless. I was thinking that maybe I should delay the change to the next slide until the animation is completed.

Comment: Have you considered using the [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi No, I didn't. The onAnimationEnd should be added onto the next and previous buttons? And how exacly does it work? It activates after an animation occurs or?

Comment: It should be added to the slide, or more precisely to the element that is animated (the element that moves). It triggers when the animation ends so you can do whatever you need to do after the animation.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi this might be a little bit tricky because I have a <Carousel/> component and inside of it I have the <Slide/> components. And basically the <Slide/> moves, but the state itself is inside the <Carousel/> component.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, the `Carousel` component can provide the animation end event handler as a function prop to `Slide`, something like `<Slide onAnimationEnd={ this._onAnimationEnd } />`. That way, the event is called from within the slide but everything is handled outside in the carousel.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi I cannot seem to get it working with the onAnimationEnd. I even wrote a simple test div and button inside the Carousel, but it doesn't behave the way it should. Something that I observed is that even if I don't interact with an element that has the onAnimationEnd attribute set, it triggers when I interact with other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I cannot remove the added class in such a manner that it won't break the autoplay feature.

```
    setNextSlideStates(){
        this.setState({
            // remove rightSlide state
            rightSlide: false,
            // update the active slide state
            activeSlide: this.nextSlide()
        });
    }
    // for usert button click handler, set withAnimation to false.
    handleButtonNext(withAnimation) {
        if(this.carouselTimer) clearTimeout(this.carouselTimer)
        // if there are any animations, terminate them and call setNextSlideStates manually
        if(this.animationTimer) {clearTimeout(this.animationTimer); this.setNextSlideStates(); }
        // start the animation
        this.setState({
            rightSlide: true
        });
        // wait 1.1 sec for animation to end
        this.animationTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setNextSlideStates()
            this.animationTimer = null;
            // autoplay the next slide
            this.carouselTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                this.handleButtonNext(true);
            }, 3900);
        }, withAnimation ? 1100 : 0)
    }
```

Also change your componentDidMount to:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.carouselTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.handleButtonNext(true);
        }, 3900);
    }
```

Button Handler:

```
{/* no animation */}
<button onClick={() => {this.handleButtonNext(false)}}>next</button>
```

Comment: Although this might work, it's important to keep in mind that an arbitrary wait time is configured here. So it needs to be equal or greater than the animation time, not to mention the need to update the wait value manually if you decide to update the CSS animation time. That's why I suggested using the [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) event.

Comment: This indeed adds and the removes the class, but it starts an infinite loop that changes the slides every 1 second. And the desired behavior is that when the button is clicked, the class is added > the animation happens > the class is removed > the slides now are changed > and it start the autoplay timer that changes the slides every 5s.

Comment: @pustiul500 updated the code. now it waits 3.9 sec, then starts the animation, then after 1.1 it animation will stop, and after 3.9 sec it will get fired again.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi sure, however this question seems to be more about react state management, so i didn't care about the actual animation stuff.

Comment: @pustiul500 wait, i did wrote `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`, my bad. (as you said: `the prev code was starting an infinite loop that changes the slides every 1 second`). updated the answer.

Comment: @yaya after changing the second property from the state, "activeSlide" you need to close the setState with }) otherwise it won't work.

This basically does what I was asking, adding and then removing a class, but if I manually press the button it kinda breaks the entire autoplay feature. It doesn't know how yo reset itself.

Comment: @pustiul500 yes there was a syntax mistake, edited. i also updated the code to stop the callbacks. and also if the animation is not done yet, it will call `nextSlide` manually. so it should fix your new issue.

Comment: @pustiul500 i noticed that you had already a function called `nextSlide`, the new `nextslide` is different, so i renamed it. also there was another issue in the code which is fixed now (the new function wasn't callable ofter timeout, so i converted it to a class method.) (updated the answer).

Comment: @pustiul500 also changed the button click handler to go to the next slide without animation. (if you want it). (for button click handler, you can also check if the `rightSlide` state is true, it means it's currently on an animation , so do nothing.) (`() => {if(this.state.rightSlide) {} else {this.handleButtonNext(true)}}`)